# what can I say about the matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let A be real square matrix of order $n \geq 6$.
>
> 1. if $a < 0$ is eigenvalue of $A^2$, then A is symmetric.
> 2. if A has no real eigenvalues, then its invariant subspaces are only $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{0\}$.
> 3. if A has no real eigenvalues, then A is nonsingular
> 4. if A has n linearly independent real eigen vectors, then A is symmetric.

Could you please help me solve this.

I have an idea only about (3). If $0$ isn't among A's eigenvalues, then A is non-singular indeed, i.e. (3) is true.

Comment: 1) is false, 3) is true and 4) is false (it's diagonalizable, not symetric). Don't know about 2

Comment: Looks like I've figured out the counterexample for (2): $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @AvaSkovko Your example is not a square matrix of order $\ge 6$. One should take a block matrix with this matrix inside.

Comment: 2 is false, since nobody else has said

Comment: @AvaSkovko your example is not actually a counterexample.  There are no counterexamples for $n = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surely 1. is false. If $A$ is symmetric all eigenvalues are real so all eigenvalues of $A^2$ are non-negative being the squares of those of $A.$

2 and 4 are also false I think

Comment: So "all eigenvalues of $A^2$ are non-negative" applies only for symmetric matrices? I used to think that for any matrix.

Comment: @AvaSkovko Any matrix with real eigenvalues. And $A$ symetric implies that all eigenvalue of $A$ are real, hence their square is $\ge 0$